# On the semigroup of the diffusion equation.

Tags: operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

[image]

[image]

Hello. I cannot understand the conclusion of the study of the diffusion equation in "one-parameter semigroups of positive operators".
More specifically the part where it is said that $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ is the semigroup generated by the closure of the second derivative with domain $D(B)$.

**Question 1**. Does this mean that $A=\overline{B}$, right?

**Question 2**. The above is true since; $E_0$  dense in $D(A)$ with $\left\|\cdot \right\|_{A}$ (graph norm of $A$) and $\left.A\right|_{E_0}=B \Rightarrow A = \overline{B}?$ (This is part of an overall result?)

I ask this to see if I understand it correctly.

I attach in images the definitions that appear in the book for clarity.
[image]
[image]